# Swift Firebase Email Verification always returning false

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to make this work but `isEmailVerified` keeps returning false... even thought I clearly verified the email.

> User Creation

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: Email.text!, password: Password.text!) { (user:FIRUser?, error:Error?) in
            if error == nil {

                let when = DispatchTime.now() + 1
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when) {

                    FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in

                        let post2 = UIAlertController(title: "Verification sent", message: "A Email will be sent to activate your account.", preferredStyle: .alert)

                        post2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (_) in


                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Sign_in", sender: nil)

                        }))

                        self.present(post2, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    })
                }

            } else {

                self.ErrorMsg.isHidden = false

                self.Password.text = ""

                print(error.debugDescription)
            }

        }
```

> User Verification

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in

            if let user = user {
                Shared.shared.User_ID = user.uid
                Shared.shared.User_Email = user.email

                if user.isEmailVerified {

                    // Email Verified
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Launch_L", sender: nil)

                } else {

                    self.logOut.isHidden = false

                }

            } else {
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Launch_S", sender: nil)
            }

        }
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @cyril yup I contacted support, I needed​ to put 'FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.reload()' before checking if the user is verified

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I simply needed to refresh the profile with:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.reload()
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload()
```

Comment: Do you think this question is particularly about Swift 5 ?

Comment: @karthicknagarajan: It’s pretty common to update old answers with updated solutions for newer languages, platforms, and libraries. If people are finding this answer today, they’re likely interested in an answer for Swift 5. This also helps prevent the need to introduce really similar questions for each version.